# как перенести элементы из списка в существующий словарь обходя функцию Counter

Tags: python, list, словари

я написал код, он работает:

```
from collections import Counter
inv = {'cold coin': 42, 'rupe': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'sword': 1}
dragonLoot = ['cold coin', 'cold coin', 'cold coin', 'robe', 'sword']
print('Inventory')

def addToInventroy(inventory, addedLoot):
    newInv = Counter(inventory) + Counter(addedLoot)
    total = 0
    for k, v in newInv.items():
        print(k + ' ' + str(v))
        total += v
    print('total: ' + str(total))

addToInventroy(inv, dragonLoot)
```

но можно ли как-то так записать, чтобы он добавлял елементы из списка в словарь обходя функцию Counter? я размышлял, что-то на подобее

```
def addToInventroy(inventory, addedLoot):
    for k, v in inventory:
         for k in range(len(addedLoot):
             if k in inventory:
                 inventory[k] = inventory[k] + 1                    

addToInventroy(inv, dragonLoot)
```

заранее благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
inv = {'cold coin': 42, 'rupe': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'sword': 1}
dragonLoot = ['cold coin', 'cold coin', 'cold coin', 'robe', 'sword']

def add_items(d: dict, l: list)-> dict:
    for i in l:
        d.setdefault(i, 0)
        d[i]+=1
    return d
        
print(add_items(inv, dragonLoot))
# {'cold coin': 45, 'rupe': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'sword': 2, 'robe': 1}
```